# How to restrict access to edit image file while still giving permission to edit image title?

Tags: 8, users, media

I want to restrict the possibility to edit or delete the image file, but still make it possible for users to edit the alt and title attribute.

What is best approach to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using [Image Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_field_permissions) module.

The Image Field Permissions allows you to set permissions to view, create and edit the image file, title and alt attributes.